# Using THREEJS OrbitControls with ES6 module import

Tags: three.js, controls

When I'm trying to import OrbitControls from the ThreeJS examples, the following errors appear: `Attempted import error: 'OrbitControls' is not exported from 'three' (imported as 'THREE').`

Here is an example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/lyz5y4kq0z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is now a very simple solution using the standard "three" npm package, just :

```
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls'
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module.

Comment: Well, it does work ! The message you have is not ugly, and rather informative : you need to use type=module in the caller <script> tag, like <script src="myscript.js" type="module"></script>

Answer (score -1):

**DEPRECATED, PLEASE CHECK https://stackoverflow.com/a/65619187/7355534**

---

I finally solved my issue with a simple solution: I removed the code example provided by ThreeJS and I replaced it with a fix.

I've published the corrective here (with some doc): https://gist.github.com/bastienrobert/f381d642da9abaaaf271866db9da59a7

If you have any recommandations, be free to comment!

Comment: You don't need this ugly fix, just import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls' and specify the type="module" attribute in the <script> tag.

Comment: Yup, thanks @AliceOualouest, this is why I've upvoted your comment and set it as the right answer ;)

Answer (score -1):

I think you're trying to access OrbitControls from the instance of THRRE like below

```
const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls();
```

But you should try to access the Orbitcontrols like following way

```
const controls = new OrbitControls();
```

You can't get rid of this error, if you try to initiate it from THREE. Thanks